Error when cordova run android. FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
enter image description here
C:\Users\PC\MyApp>cordova run android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre-1.8\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -Duser.country=RU -Duser.language=ru -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\PC\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.6-all\9f832ih6bniajn45pbmqhk2cw\gradle-7.6\lib\gradle-launcher-7.6.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 7.6
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\PC\MyApp\platforms\android\gradlew -b C:\Users\PC\MyApp\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug

I don't understand what my mistake is. I will be very grateful for any help
Before this I had a problem similar to this https://discuss.gradle.org/t/download-wrapper-fails-with-sslhandshakeexception-stacktrace/32719
I solved this problem by updating java to version "1.8.0_411", now I have an error starting Daemon
